# How to align/ format output in python

Tags: python, class, methods, format, alignment

Hey I am building a class and in one of the methods the instruction is:

A long representation of the reviews for the movie, called longReview. This method
takes no parameters. This method should return (as a string) a more detailed review of
the movie.

[Reference picture of correct format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzr5g.png)

Note that the colons must line up, and there is no space between the 5 stars and the
colon in the third line of the review. You do not need to worry about aligning the
numbers after the column – put a single space after the colon, and then the number of
reviews of that type. The average review is rounded to one decimal place.

How would I build this so that my return output looks the same as that picture
I know I would include elements like

```
def longReview(self):
    # #this is what I want it to look like
    # Dune (2021)
    # Average Review: 4.7/5
    # *****: 2
    # **** : 1
    # ***  : 0
    # **   : 0
    # *    : 0

    return "{} {}".format(self.title,self.year) /n "Average Review: {}/5".format(self.review)
```

but I am unsure how to do the star thing and make sure everything is properly aligned

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to use string formating :

```py
>>> print('{:<5}: {}'.format('*****', 2))
*****: 2
>>> print('{:<5}: {}'.format('****', 1))
**** : 1
>>> print('{:<5}: {}'.format('***', 0))
***  : 0
>>> print('{:<5}: {}'.format('*', 0))
 *    : 0
```

in the formating `{:<5}` the 5 means you want it to always take 5 caracters and the `<` means you want to align it to the left.

Complete doc here : https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Comment: but how would I use this if I need it to be in a single return statement

Comment: It would be a lot cleaner to not do it in a single return statement. Build your string step by step, you can do the star thing in a for loop for example, it depends of how you can access the data.
Remember the zen of python : Sparse is better than dense.